Should tags zmq and zeromq be merged?
tags [zmq] and [zeromq] are different names for the same thing. 
Should they be merged (e.g. zmq made an alias of zeromq) and given a description?

I agree they should be merged, but "Yes." is evidently too short an answer

Thanks for bringing that to our attention. I've merged zmq into zeromq!
